# google search console not showing clicks

Tags: seo, google-search-console, keywords

I was sadly surprised to see that google removed the search keyword queries from the referer / referrer [quite a while ago](https://marketingland.com/dark-google-search-terms-not-provided-one-year-later-24341).

Now they do provide us with [google search console](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/)

but it is kind of useless

In my case, I have registered 470 clicks, but look at that, only 2!!! Two clicks show in the report.

[image]

This report is not an exception, search console always showed me basically little to almost no info about what was giving me actually clicks

How should I know what keywords are my money makers?

use a different tool altogether?

Comment: My guess is that they are working on the new version of GSC and don't care about the gaps or errors at the previous version. We should wait or analyze from another point of view (rank + page analytics + conversion)

Comment: What if you look at page level, not query level?

Comment: @max yes it will show clicks in pages. But I really want to know the search keywords

Comment: @Emirodgar I didnt notice there is a new one. Looking at the new one though: queries and clicks are just equally as bad. It's the same data, shows 2 clicks on queries, but should be 470.

Comment: After clicking pages you can then click the keyword filter to see keywords for that page. Might be more data in there, but only on a page by page basis, whuch isnt as easy.

Answer (score 4):

The report does not show all queries:

"Very rare queries are not shown in these results to protect the privacy of the user making the query."
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6155685?hl=en

So your site may be getting lots of one-off queries where people click.